# Activity indicator freezes during navigation

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to fix the freezing of activity indicator on android device.

When I navigate from login page to main page, the activity indicator start correctly on login page but then get stuck (still on login page) for few seconds before the main page is finally displayed.

If I delete functions calls on main component startup I still have the problem, so I don't think a worker would solve the problem.
If i delete a bunch of things in the main page HTML file the problem disappears.

What should I do to ? Can I get a worker to load the UI ? Should I divide my main component into few sub-component ?

Comment: It may be some heavy operation you are performing while navigating to or from a page. Do you have a Playground sample?

Comment: @Manoj unfortunately I can't provide a sample for now. What kind of heavy operations you have in mind ? As I've said the activity indicator still freezes without any function calls on main component startup. So I cant think of anymore operation except the UI loading. And I only pass a boolean from login to main navigation.

Comment: May be you are rendering too many UI elements while it starts which could be done lazily Or your layout is may be too heavy. A common mistake I have seen is that people use GridLayout to stack items on vertical / horizontal direction, the more number of partition may slow down rendering process which could be avoided by StackLayout. It could possibly be anything, without a sample it's hard to tell. You may use Android's layout inspector to see where exactly it's taking too much time.